# Altering queryset parameters in django models

Tags: django-models

In a django model I would like to modify the parameters of a queryset before running it.

I'm creating an object MyModel with :

```
m = MyModel(name="name", value="value")
m.save()
```

In my save method I hash name and value before inserting them. This is working fine.

After this I would like to do :

```
MyModel.objects.get(name="name", value="value")
```

to know I name and value are already in my database.

I tryed with manager by I don't find a way to get the queryset params

oau

Answer (score 0):

the answer is manager :

```
class ModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
         // modify args here
         return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
```